# Adding behavior to a class dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a class that has a set of properties. What I am trying to do is to dynamically at runtime add custom lines of code that will run when a property setter is called.

Is there a way to achieve this? or at least a way to create a proxy class that will wrap the original class the way Entity Framework and mocking frameworks does it?

Comment: Can you modify the class?

Comment: No, I don't own the class.

Comment: Are you unable to inherit from this class as well?

Comment: Does the class implement an interface to which you could program? I.e. something like `IMyDataObject {int Prop1{get} string Prop2{get;set;}}` on the class like this: `MyDataObject : IMyDataObject {...}`?

Comment: Hi Sisyphus - what you are suggesting would require dynamically unloading and then reloading the class. This is something that can be done in Java, but I don't think that C#/.NET has this ability. You mention doing DI with MEF - have you considered using some sort of action/command pattern to get the functionality that you want? if you have some code (or pseudo-code) demonstrating what you are trying to do, I'm sure someone here could make a recommendation as to what to use.

Comment: I can inherit, but I am trying to do this at runtime because my code doesn't know the type of the class it will be dealing with. I should grab the class loop through its properties and add a certain line of code to each setter I meet.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight no I don't have interface.

Comment: @darkpbj could you please explain your solution using the action/command pattern as an answer, I am not sure I got what you mean.

Comment: Can you use external libraries, such as [this one](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight looks promising, however I would leave it as last resort as I would prefer to use an organic .net method to reduce external dependencies.

Comment: @Sisyphus Given your constraints (inability to make changes to the class and lack of an interface) coding up a robust solution could be very tricky. It's not impossible, though, because C# has multiple ways of generating code at run-time.

Comment: Without using external libraries you will just spent your time reinventing those sams libraries.

Answer (score 1):

**I advise against dynamically adding behavior to a class that you did not write.** This violates the [Open-Closed Principle](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613119/SOLID-Principles-The-Open-Closed-Principle-What-Wh), which states:

> Software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open
>   for extension, but closed for modification.

In this case where the program will not know what the class structure looks like until runtime, your only option to access methods / properties will be (as you suggested) to wrap the original class and use Reflection to access class members.

Here is an (untested) example of what a wrapper class might look like using **Reflection** to access properties on your object:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class ProxyClass
{
    public Type   WrappedType   { get; private set; }
    public Object WrappedObject { get; private set; }


    public ProxyClass(Object wrappedObject)
    {
        WrappedObject = wrappedObject;
        WrappedType   = wrappedObject.GetType();

    } // end constructor

    public object GetPropVal(String propName)
    {
        return WrappedType.GetProperty(propName).GetValue(WrappedObject, null);
    } // end GetPropVal

    public void SetPropVal(String propName, Object val)
    {
        WrappedType.GetProperty(propName).SetValue(WrappedObject, val, null);
    } // end SetPropVal

} // end class ProxyClass
```

For further reading, look at documentation on the [Type.GetProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) method - this will be helpful in determining whether a certain property does or does not exist on the object that you are trying to wrap.